# constexpr difference between gcc v10 and v9: bug or feature

Tags: c++, constexpr, constant-expression

If compiled with gcc v10 the code below exibits an error but for gcc v9 the code is ok.

```
template<auto N>
struct A {
    constexpr auto size() const {
        return N;
    }  
};

template<typename T>
void foo1(const T& a) {
    constexpr auto s = a.size(); // Why error here?
}
template<typename T>
void foo2(T a) {
    constexpr auto s = a.size(); // OK
}
int main() {
    A<10> x1;
    foo1(x1);
    foo2(x1);
    A<x1.size()> x2; // OK
    constexpr auto s = x1.size(); // OK
}
```

In my understanding the memberfunction size() could be called constexpr in all cases. But there is one case where the behaviour of gcc10 changed compared to gcc9: if the argument is passed by const-ref.
I don't understand why this should not be constexpr?

Another example:

```
template<auto N>
struct A {
    constexpr auto size() const {
        return N;
    }  
};

template<typename T>
constexpr void foo1(const T& a) {
    constexpr auto s = a.size(); // Why error here?
    return s;
}
template<typename T>
constexpr auto foo2(const T& a) {
    return a.size(); // Why OK here
}
int main() {
    A<10> x1;
    constexpr auto s1 = foo1(x1);
    constexpr auto s2 = foo2(x1);
}
```

I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Would be helpful to show the actual error.

Comment: `test93.cc:10:20: error: 'a' is not a constant expression
10 |     constexpr auto s = a.size(); // Why error here?
|                    ^`

Comment: FYI: seems like clang and MSVC also claim that it is an error.

Comment: clang and msvc also claims for an error [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/DR_uE7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [GCC bug 66477](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66477). It mentions that GCC wrongly accepts reference-type parameters in constant expressions.

This bug is fixed for GCC 10.

---

The reason why `a.size()` is not allowed in constant expressions is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54124899/5376789).

Comment: Well, I don't get it right. I added another example to the question.

Comment: @wimalopaan A constexpr function doesn't require all the expressions in its body to be constant expressions, while the initializer of a constexpr variable must be a constant expression.