# boost::hana::length fails to give a constexpr result when using references

Tags: c++, boost-hana

In the following function:

```cpp
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(const T& obj){
    constexpr int size = hana::length(obj);
}
```

When called e.g. with `f(hana::make_tuple())`, it produces an error:

> constexpr variable 'size' must be initialized by a constant expression.

Passing by value doesn't have issues.

Does anyone know the reason and how to work around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124899/why-is-a-constexpr-function-on-a-reference-not-constexpr

Comment: One workaround is to wrap it in decltype: `decltype(hana::length(obj))::value`

Comment: @JasonRice, yeah, that works. On the reason, I didn't know of the limitations of references passed to constexpr functions, thanks!