# Can't use if constexpr with a reference parameter to a constexpr function

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, constexpr

My code below produces the following error:

> C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant.

```
    template<int32_t M, int32_t N>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr double determinant(const Matrix<M,N> & m)
    {
        double det = 0;
        if constexpr(m.rows() == 2)
        {
            return m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0];
        }
        else
        {
            for(std::size_t col = 0; col < m.cols(); ++col)
            {
                det += m[0][col] * cofactor(m, 0, col);
            }
        }
        return det;
    }
```

My "first" error with regular if statement was:

> C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex.

Someone here on stackoverflow had a similar error while doing similar stuff, his solution was to use `if constexpr` because otherwise the if statement could not be evaluated at compile time. But this produces my current error C2131.

`Matrix<M,N>` has a method `rows()` which is also `constexpr`. Can someone explain to me why this code won't compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Matrix<M, N>` defines `rows()` to return `M`, just replace

```
if constexpr (m.rows() == 2)
```

with

```
if constexpr (M == 2)
```

`m.rows()` does not produce a constant expression even if `rows()` is marked as a `constexpr` because `m` is a reference. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124899/why-is-a-constexpr-function-on-a-reference-not-constexpr) is an explanation why.