# What is the correlation of this accepted answer to the context of reference and constexpr?

Tags: reference, constexpr

My reference is to the following post:

[Why is a constexpr function on a reference not constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124899/why-is-a-constexpr-function-on-a-reference-not-constexpr)

I read through the other answers and it made sense except for [the answer accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128531/367865) by the creator of the post:

> Unfortunately, the standard states that in a class member access expression *The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;<sup>63</sup>* [[expr.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#1). A postfix expression is `a` in `a.b`. The note is really interesting because this is precisely the case here:
>
> > 63. If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, for example if the id-expression denotes a static member.
>
> So `data` is evaluated even if it would not be necessary and the rule fore constant expression applies on it too.

What is the correlation to the context of reference and constexpr? Can someone explain?